# How can I access a variable defined in the parent template in PHP smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have a main template which includes a lot of others.
How can I access a variable defined in the parent template from the included ones in PHP smarty?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameter to children template when you include them.

Example :

```
{include file='children.tpl' somevar=$somevar}
```

In your children template, `somevar` will now be accessible.